# How to make a shared partition between dual-booted Windows 7 and Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, linux, partitioning, multi-boot, shared-folders

I have a lot of files that I would like to access from both of my dual-booted OS's. How do I make a shared folder? Is there a simpler method? (Like some kind of a shared folder, although I doubt that because of different filesystem formats and all that...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create and NTFS partition and set up it to [mount automatically](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) on ubuntu start.
You can edit the file [`/etc/fstab`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab) and include a line like this:

```
/dev/sda10 /media/Winbugs7/ ntfs-3g defaults,user,rw    0   0
```

Where `/dev/sda10` is the partition and `/media/Winbugs7` is the (existing!) directory where the partition will be mounted.

*More reading at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions*

Answer (score 2):

You just create seperated partition in NTFS format..you can easily access that from both ubuntu and windows.

Answer (score 2):

While Ubuntu will automatically mount your windows NTFS partition so you can access the windows drive from Ubuntu. You can install [Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) on your windows install and that will allow you to access the ubuntu ext3/ext4 partition from windows explorer.

If you don't want any extra software on your windows install to do this. You could either create a new NTFS partition as @aleo0317 has already answered or you can create a folder in your windows NTFS Partition that is already mounted. Why create a whole new partition when you have one for windows that can be accessed by both OS's.

Cheers I hope this helps.